# Table with live processing angular 5

Tags: html-table, .net-core, angular5, reactivex

I have to create a table, such that it sends Http Request with a parameter (first column value) for each row in the table and shows processing status for that request.
There is same backend process for each row with a column value passed as a parameter.
On completion of the request for the first row, the status column in the table should show 'Success' and then the request for the second record should be sent.
The request should be sent synchronously as there is moderately heavy backend process attached i.e. on completion of the previous request only next request has to be sent.
I have to achieve this using Angular 5 and DotNet Core 2.0.
Please let me know if there is a feature already available for doing such a thing in Angular 5 and .net Core in an optimized way. I have heard of ReactiveX but I am not able to figure out the best way to achieve this as Reactivex is for asynchronous programming.
Any suggestions or similar examples on this would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I hav tried creating a table with ngfor and then sending http request for each row but i have nt implemented showing status on completion of each request